# How to stay on the same page after form submit thymleaf and Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redirect, thymeleaf

Hello guys i have a question regarding what is mentioned in the title. Is it possible to stay on the same page and submit . I found something with javascript but it is not working for me because i m using thymleaf and spring boot. Or i just don't know how to  adapt  it to my case.

thymeleaf code:

```
<form th:action="@{/tweets/tweet}" th:object="${tweet}" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" class="form-control"  placeholder="What's happening? Tell us!">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

the controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("tweets")
@Slf4j
public class TweetController {

 private TweetService tweetService;

public TweetController(TweetService tweetService) {
this.tweetService = tweetService;
}


@PostMapping("/tweet")
@ResponseStatus(CREATED)
public Tweet tweet(@Valid @ModelAttribute("tweet")  Tweet tweet, Principal 
principal, BindingResult result) {
if(result.hasErrors()){

   //do somethign
}

if (!tweet.getContent().equals(null) && !tweet.getContent().equals("") && !tweet.getContent().isEmpty()) {
  tweetService.createTweet(tweet.getContent(), principal);
}

 }

 @GetMapping("/")
 public String goToIndex(Model model){
   model.addAttribute("tweet",new Tweet());
return "overview";
}
```

And i have `server.context-path=/api`

I have one more additional question to this topic. When i wanted to redirect it to another page i was getting a blank page. Not an error not an exception just a blank page. Any help ? I m new to this.

Comment: You need to use Javascript and AJAX calls if you don't want to fully reload the page. Alternatively you must do the classical submit and reload the same page after the submit

Comment: I would love to reload the same page after submitting   but i m just getting a blank white page

Comment: This is a pretty common and often answered question that isn't spring specific. This might get you pointed in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717820/using-ajax-with-spring-mvc/46776756

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible using `ajax`. I would recommend doing it using `jQuery` though. So, if you would like to submit your form and stay in the same page, you could do the following.

**HTML**

```
<form id="tweet-form" th:action="@{/tweets/tweet}" th:object="${tweet}" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" class="form-control"  placeholder="What's happening? Tell us!">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input id="submit-form" class="form-control" type="button" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Changes:**

- Added an id to the form.
- Added an id to your input.
- Change submit input's type for button.

**jQuery**

```
$('#submit-form').on('click', function() {
   var form = $('#tweet-form');
   $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      type: post,
      success: function(result) {
          // Do something with the response.
          // Might want to check for errors here.
      }, error: function(error) {
          // Here you can handle exceptions thrown by the server or your controller.
      }
   })
}
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/tweet")
@ResponseStatus(CREATED)
public Tweet tweet(@Valid @ModelAttribute("tweet")  Tweet tweet, Principal 
principal, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        // Throw an exception or send a null Tweet.
    }
    if (!tweet.getContent().equals(null) && !tweet.getContent().equals("") && !tweet.getContent().isEmpty()) {
        tweetService.createTweet(tweet.getContent(), principal);
    }
    // You are returning a Tweet, so you must return something. 
    return tweet;
}
```

Your controller pretty much stay the same. Just remember to return something.

Comment: is it possible to refresh list of tweets using same methodology ?

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't show what the `tweet()` method returns. It should return a `Tweet` object but doesn't have any return value. What are you attempting to do with that return value? If you're not handling it with Javascript someway, then get rid of `@ResponseStatus(CREATED)` and return a either a `Model` or a `String` pointing to your html file, like so:

```
@PostMapping("/tweet")
public String tweet(@Valid @ModelAttribute("tweet")  Tweet tweet, Principal 
principal, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()){
       //do somethign
    }

    if (!tweet.getContent().equals(null) && !tweet.getContent().equals("") && !tweet.getContent().isEmpty()) {
        tweetService.createTweet(tweet.getContent(), principal);
    }
    return "redirect:/name-of-html-file";
}
```

[reference](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

If you want thymeleaf to handle the tweet and the HttpStatus you could instead return something along the lines of

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("your-view");
model.addAttribute(tweet);
model.setStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED);
return model;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local URI `/tweet` that should result in a download of file `tweet.zip` while staying on the same page, do the following:

HTML

```
  <a th:href="@{|/tweet|}" download>Tweet</a>
```

Java Controller

```
@GetMapping("/tweet")
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource tweet(
    HttpServletResponse response
) {
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=tweet.zip");
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    File zip = ...; // create your own ZIP file here
    return new FileSystemResource(zip);
}
```